# Joining literal text to a variable (string concatenation) in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have: `String = "there"`

I have tried various things such as: `"Hello " ++ String` and `string:concat("Hello", String)`.  The output always ends up with the literal string "Hello" being the integers representing the characters of the string, instead of the letters.

How can I combine a literal string and a string in a variable, in Erlang?

Comment: everything is working. Use shell:strings(true) for output to a string representation.

Comment: If there are unicode strings and You tried to concatenate strings in shell, so You have to start shell with  +pc unicode param. To check if You have unicode shell - issue io:getopts() command. You have to find {encoding,unicode} tuple.

Answer (score 11):

Works for me.

```
1> String = "there".
"there"
2> "Hello " ++ String.
"Hello there"
```